# Placing elements linearly in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new to android and trying to place the elements horizontally using android apis without xml.

What I'm trying to do is to place RadioButtons and EditText horizontally. Something like:

```
R-----E
R-----E
```

I tried code like this:

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : storedCards.entrySet())
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    EditText ed = new EditText(this);
    RadioButton rb  = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setId(counter++);

    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,rb.getId());
    ed.setLayoutParams(lp2);

    rg.addView(rb); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
    rb.setText(entry.getKey());
    relativeLayout.addView(ed);
}
```

This doesn't work. But this is what I'm trying to do : First I'm setting the id for each radiobutton using the `counter` variable and trying to set edittext view on the right hand site of that radio button using:

```
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,rb.getId());
```

But I'm not getting proper result. I get only like this:

```
ER
R
```

all `EditText` are being overlapped. Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect `RelativeLayout` to place views relative to other views that it does not contain.  The `RelativeLayout` does not understand the ids of the `RadioButtons` because they haven't been added to it.  Consequently, a `RadioButton` added to any other layout except for `RadioGroup` (which is just a `LinearLayout`) will not have the mutual exclusion logic you are probably looking for when the user taps them to be checked.

So you must lay out your `RadioButton` items in a vertical `RadioGroup`, and the simplest way to have your `EditText` items line up next to them is to create a second `LinearLayout` next to it, and use fixed height to ensure each "row" matches.  Something like:

```
LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

RadioGroup buttonGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
buttonGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout editLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
editLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Add left/right pane to root layout
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
root.addView(buttonGroup, lp);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
root.addView(editLayout, lp);

//Fixed height for each row item (45dp in this case)
//Getting DP values in Java code is really ugly, which is why we use XML for this stuff
int rowHeightDp = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 45.0f, getResources.getDisplayMetrics());

for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : storedCards.entrySet())
{

    EditText ed = new EditText(this);
    RadioButton rb  = new RadioButton(this);
    rb.setId(counter++);
    rb.setText(entry.getKey());

    //Add each item with its LayoutParams
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        rowHeightDp) );
    buttonGroup.addView(rb, lp1);

    lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        rowHeightDp) );
    editLayout.addView(ed, lp1);
}
```

This creates two side-by-side layouts that stay lined up due to the fixed item height.  You can adjust the item height in the `LayoutParams` used for each row.  You can see how doing layouts in pure Java is extremely verbose, which is the reason the preferred method is XML.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Worked like a charm! Ya I agree that its pretty bad to understand the java code. But I want to generate the view based on the map entry on `storedCards`; So I guess xml in this case wont help me rather I need to code the layout myself!

Comment: That's not really true, it just means you cant define your entire layout in a single XML file.  You can define the root and containers in one layout, the other elements in their own XML files, and inflate/attach in Java code.  This way the layout is still dynamic, but you don't have to write out all the LayoutParams.